# HTTP POST call from Azure custom API Script not working

Tags: javascript, azure, http-post, google-forms

I have a custom Azure API, which I'd like to execute a HTTP POST request.  In this case to Google Forms, but I think this is a general question.  What I'm finding is that the POST request seems to go through - the Google Form gets a response - but no data comes through.

Here's my script:

```
exports.get = function(request, response) {
 var p = request.parameters;
 var item = JSON.stringify({entry_123456: "LOGIN", entry_234567: request.query.Email, entry_345678: request.query.Token }); 
    require('request').post({
        uri : 'https://docs.google.com/forms/d/myformkeyhere/formResponse',
        headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        body : item
    }, function(err, res, body){
        if (err)
        {
             request.respond(500, "Error: " + err + "; item: " + item); 
        }
        else
        {
            request.respond(200,"Success"); 
        }
    });
    response.send(statusCodes.OK, { message : item + "; response=" + response });
};
```

I'm testing it with this address in my browser:

```
https://myservice.azure-mobile.net/api/user?Email=testEmail@gmail.com&Token=YayToken
```

I'm getting this response back to my browser:

```
{"message":"{\"entry_123456\":\"LOGIN\",\"entry_234567\":\"testEmail@gmail.com\",\"entry_345678\":\"YayToken\"}; response=[object Object]"}
```

I thought I'd followed the directions in the documentation, but I've hit a wall.  Anyone have experience with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got my answer on [MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/34e1382a-4ba8-4f62-a294-4383c3e75ebb/http-post-call-from-azure-custom-api-script-not-working?forum=azuremobile):

I looked at the script and these are the problems that I found with the script.

I am not sure if 'request' client support 'application/json' POST. As per the documentation, they support URL encoding. https://github.com/mikeal/request#forms
There is some mixup in the request.respond and response.send

Thanks for creating the Google form. I loaded the URL in IE and figured out that they use url encoding for form posting and this should be doable using the request library.

Here is the code that should work for you. You can easily test it by running https://forumtest.azure-mobile.net/api/gdocs/?Data1=XYZ&Data2=ABC&Data3=BBC and seeing the variables you entered from previous responses in https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1DcvdfKSo4JK-9RFAdO5We8nYwT9e604V_HH1uHf8ges/viewanalytics?usp=form_confirm

```
exports.get = function(request, response) {   
    var googleRequest = require('request');
    var googleUrl = 'https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1DcvdfKSo4JK-9RFAdO5We8nYwT9e604V_HH1uHf8ges/formResponse';
    var r = googleRequest.post(
        googleUrl,
        { form: { 'entry.1173958467':request.query.Data1, 
                  'entry.240822405':request.query.Data2,
                  'entry.976020097':request.query.Data3 } }, 
        function optionalCallback (err, httpResponse, body) {
          if (err) {
            console.error('upload failed:', err);
            response.send(statusCodes.OK, { message : 'Failure' });
          } else {
            console.log('Upload successful!  Server responded with:', body);
            response.send(statusCodes.OK, { message : 'Success' });
          }
        });
};
```

Hope this helps.
[Manesh Raveendran](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/manesh%20raveendran/?ws=usercard-mini)
Terawe Corporation